# Bookmarklet only Triggers Click on First Element instead of All

Tags: javascript, github, bookmarklet

I'm trying to write a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet#:%7E:text=A%20bookmarklet%20is%20a%20bookmark,when%20user%20clicks%20on%20them.) that deletes all the merged and closed branches on a Github project. The idea is that it would get the delete buttons for all the branches that are either merged or closed and trigger a `click()` on them. This is what I have written:

```
javascript:document.querySelectorAll('span[title="Status: Merged"], span[title="Status: Closed"]').forEach(node => node.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.js-branch-delete-button').click())
```

If I run this on the branches page, it only deletes the first branch, rather than all, even though the following returns all the node ids:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span[title="Status: Merged"], span[title="Status: Closed"]').forEach(node => console.log(node.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.js-branch-delete-button').id))
```

Any idea why this is happening? I'm not a frontend developer so fair chances it might be something very simple but I've tried all I could think of without any luck and it only deletes the first branch rather than all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you click one delete button, it disables all other delete buttons until the deleting process is finished, so we can use `MutationObserver` to wait until the currently selected delete button is not disabled, then click it. You can use this modified bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(async function(){
function waitTillNotDisabled(elm) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (!elm.disabled) {
            return resolve();
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (!elm.disabled) {
                resolve();
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}

const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('span[title="Status: Merged"], span[title="Status: Closed"]');

for (let i=0;i<deleteButtons.length;i++) {
    const deleteButton = deleteButtons[i].parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.js-branch-delete-button');
    await waitTillNotDisabled(deleteButton);
    deleteButton.click();
}
})();
```